# Using Scala Function2 Object in Java

Tags: java, scala

I have a scala program which contains a singleton that extends `Function2`. I was wondering if its possible to serialize this object and send it to a Java program, so that it can be utilized on that program?

I noticed that Java does not have a `Function2` class or interface, so I wasn't sure if this would be possible.

If it is not possible to send to a Java program, how can it be sent to a different Scala Program, and utilized appropriately?

The singleton looks something like this.

```
object add extends Function2[Int, Int, Int] {

  override def apply(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
}
```

Comment: Also note that you don't need the `override` here.

Answer (score 2):

Scala compiles to JVM bytecode in a way that's designed to support interoperability with Java. In this case if you've got an SBT build set up (or if you compile your Scala code and include the result and the Scala library jar in your classpath) you can just write the following:

```
public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(add.apply(1, 2));
  }
}
```

That's all. You don't get the nice `add(1, 2)` syntactic sugar, but otherwise it's pretty easy.

There are some complications that can come up in more advanced situations, but there's a lot of documentation around about how to work around them (and you're always welcome to ask follow-up questions here, of course).

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed that Java does not have a Function2 class or interface, so I wasn't sure if this would be possible.

You just need to include `scala-library.jar`, which contains `Function2`, on the classpath, along with your own library. You don't need to serialize the object.